# How can I get separated states from multiple child components in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I am trying to get states from multiple checkbox child components to one parent component.

I attached the link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cdn-4vcj1k)

Checkbox states of each child components working okay and checkbox also changes accordingly.

However when I try to send those states up and integrate inside of parent component, it does not work as I expected.

I want to combine those states as an object literal inside of parent state according to toggle state.

For instance, when all vegetable and some of Languages are checked, I want to set state in parent component like below.

```
{
  Vegetables-Carrot: true, 
  Vegetables-Potato: true, 
  Vegetables-Tomato: true,
  Languages-EN: true,
  Languages-ESP: true,
}
```

On the other hand, when Vegetables options are unchecked, I want to remove those options in parent state or make values to false.

```
{
  Languages-EN: true,
  Languages-ESP: true,
}

or 

{
  Vegetables-Carrot: false, 
  Vegetables-Potato: false, 
  Vegetables-Tomato: false,
  Languages-EN: true,
  Languages-ESP: true,
}
```

I thought it would work out with proper use of prevState inside of setState but it only add unnecessary options whenver checkboxes are toggled.

```
{
  Vegetables-Carrot: true, 
  Vegetables-Potato: true, 
  Vegetables-Tomato: true,
  Languages-EN: true,
  Languages-ESP: true,
  Vegetables-Carrot: true, 
  Vegetables-Potato: true, 
  Vegetables-Tomato: true,
}
```

Many hours of trying but no progress at all. How can I manipulate those states inside of parent component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution for your example would be to only have state management under `App` component like in [this solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-leaf-sm5onm).

You could have 2 states, one in `App` and the other in `MyCheckbox` but this would require you to change a little bit the logic under `MyCheckbox` like this:

```js
// instead of doing this
useEffect(() => {
  onChangeData(selected);
}, [ selected ]);

// you should be updating `selected` state based on a property
// here named `value` and directly call `onChangeData` in `handleChange`
useEffect(() => {
  setSelected(value);
}, [ value ]);
```

But doing this kind of approach tends to create issues of re-rendering and needs to be extra careful. So, when possible, it's best to avoid having 2 states to synchronize.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass down a setState function, and all you need to do is to make sure to create a new object and toggle the state for a specific checkbox.

**Parent component**

```
const [states, setStates] = useState({});

<CheckboxComp func={setStates} name="Vegetables-Tomato"/>
```

now in your Checkbox you can flip the state

**CheckboxComp** :

```
export default function CheckboxComp({func, name}){
  const toggleFunc = useCallback(() => func(states => {...states, name: !states[name] ?? true}, [])

  return (
    <input type="checkbox" onChange={toggleFunc}/> 
  )
}
```